# Invalid JSON primitive: object : Passing Object as a Parameter from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Am receiving a JSON object from webservice in C# using the below script

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/LogService.asmx/authenticateLogin",
            data: "{'gopId':'" + txtGopId+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) 
            {
                var k = $("#hidId").val(response.d);                   
                window.location.replace("Pages/Reved.aspx?hid="+k+"");                           
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                DisplayError(xhr);
            }
        });
```

hidId is a hidden feild.

On sucess am forwarding the Object to another aspx page and trying to deserialize this on page_load

```
         JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         userBO = serializer.Deserialize<UserBO>(Request["hid"]);
```

Am I doing some thing wrong? as iam facing this error:
Invalid JSON primitive: object

Comment: Can you show the class  `UserBO` and the content of `Request["hid"]`?

Comment: it is a simple bo with get;set.like.... public class UserBO
    {
        public string userId      { get; set; }
        public string userCode    { get; set; }}

Comment: And the content of `Request["hid"]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Invalid JSON primitive" error message means that whatever you're sending to the deserializer is not JSON. Have you verified that the value you're putting into the hidId field is valid JSON?